# Data isn't being added in Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create a website but I've been having difficulties with the database.

I've tried to create the website in C# or VB. Both of the code show that they work. But when I refresh the table, there's nothing inside. No data added.

This is the C# project code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=redacted.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=hmsproject;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx");

SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter();

string query = "INSERT INTO reservations(username,mobile) VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text+"','"+TextBox2.Text+"')";

try  
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    sqladp.SelectCommand = command;
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
}
```

and VB code:

```
Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=redacted.database.windows.net,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=hmsproject;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx")

Dim SDA As New SqlDataAdapter

Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "INSERT INTO reservations (username, number) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
    Command = New SqlCommand(Query, conn)
    SDA.SelectCommand = Command

    Label2.Text = "Awdawd"
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Note that both of the code are from 2 different projects. Not inside 1. But in both of them, I get nothing. I tried to add the values with parameters too.. still nothing

EDIT: after adding  `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()`  I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: You just posted your database address, username, and password *to the world* in your connection string. I edited it out, but I suggest you change credentials *immediately* (people with enough rep here can see all edit revisions).

Comment: You have an identity column but not sure which one it is. Post your schema...its one of the two columns.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` for the command to be executed. Otherwise you create the command and all things around it, but never execute the command.

Also please consider using [SQL parameters](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-the-right-way-to-query-a-database-parameterizing-your-sql-queries/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: in c# or vb do I have to add this?

Comment: ok. did that and it shows me an error. can you check the post again please? I updated it

Comment: That's a separate issue with your insert statement - pretty self explanatory if you read the message

Comment: for some unknown reasons that error was on VB. but in C# it worked. thanks!